# How to grab video using easycap chipset utv007 on Raspberry pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, video

I want to grab video using easy cap on my raspberry pi 3.
I followed the link http://raspberry-at-home.com/video-grabber-for-raspberry-pi/, but I am getting only green screen.

```
root@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.11-v7+ #888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

root@raspberrypi:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:0023 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1b71:3002  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@raspberrypi:~# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: usbtv [usbtv], device 0: USBTV Audio [USBTV Audio Input]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                  bcm2835 ALSA
1 [usbtv          ]: usbtv - usbtv
                  USBTV Audio at bus 1 device 12
```

How to resolve this issue?? any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:
http://easycap.blogspot.de/2013/03/raspberry-pi-and-easycap-devices.html

The video is green if there is no signal connected to the easycap.
You may check the connection of the video input.